# Simple CSS Images Side By Side

Tags: css

I'm having a problem displaying images side by side inside of an overflow box.

They seem to be going to the end of the box then going to a new line for some reason.

Here's what I got:

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:nowrap; width:500px; height:145px;">
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=9; $i++) { 
echo "<table><tr><td>";
echo "<img src=\"images/store/" . $i . ".jpg\" height=\"100px\" />"; 
echo "<br /><center><img src=\"images/store/buy.png\" width=\"75px\" /></center></td></tr></table>";
} 
?>
</div>
```

Any help would be amazing!

Comment: Why are you wrapping the contents of your loop in tables?

Comment: @Axel Because I might want to add new items later and it'd just be easier to change the number in the PHP code and then drag the image to the folder.

Comment: Your HTML markup has nothing to do with your PHP.  The use of tables in this case is considered invalid.  I've provided a detailed answer of how you can achieve proper code, that is better formatted and easier to edit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe all I really had was a  bug, and @Yamo seemed to point it out for me. Everything works fine now!

```
<div style="overflow-x:auto; overflow-y:hidden; white-space:nowrap; width:500px; height:145px;">
<table><tr>
<?php
for ($i=1; $i<=9; $i++) { 
echo "<td><img src=\"images/store/" . $i . ".jpg\" height=\"100px\" />"; 
echo "<br /><center><img src=\"images/store/buy.png\" width=\"75px\" /></center></td>";
} 
?>
</tr></table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend updating and formatting your code better, then addressing the issue you're having.

1. Don't echo out HTML tags using PHP.
2. Don't use inline-styles applied directly to the tags (use classes/ids)
3. Don't use tables, for non-tabular data.

With that said, here is a working example of what I believe you're trying to achieve:

http://jsfiddle.net/a8yDv/

**PHP/HTML:**

```
<div class="images">
    <ul>
    <?php for ($i=1; $i<=9; $i++) : ?>
        <li>
            <img src="images/store/<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg" class="top-image" alt="" />
            <img src="images/store/buy.png" class="bottom-image" alt="" />
        </li>
    <?php endfor; ?> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.images {
    border: 5px solid red;
    height: 145px;
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: 500px;
}

.images ul { 
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.images li {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center; 
}
.images img {
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.images img.top-image {
    height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.images img.bottom-image {
    width: 75px;    
}

/* Clearfix - http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/clear-fix/ */
.clearfix:after {
     visibility: hidden;
     display: block;
     font-size: 0;
     content: " ";
     clear: both;
     height: 0;
     }
.clearfix { display: inline-block; }
/* start commented backslash hack \*/
* html .clearfix { height: 1%; }
.clearfix { display: block; }
/* close commented backslash hack */
```

Comment: so every time I want to add an image I have to go edit the HTML file? That kind of defeats my purpose of using PHP, I wanted to use PHP so I could just drag images to folder then up the number.

Comment: @jadeallencook No. Simply replace the image src with what you have for an image source : `<img src="images/store/<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg" class="top-image" alt="" />`. Axel was merely providing a (better) example, not code for your specific use.

Comment: @jadeallencook My solution is using PHP.  The only difference is I'm not echoing out every single line of HTML.  I'm only using PHP to echo out PHP variables, which is really how it should be (as it's easier to read and maintain).

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `white-space:nowrap;` property in your styles:

```
div {
  overflow-x:auto; 
  overflow-y:hidden; 
  white-space:nowrap; 
  width:500px; 
  height:100px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLXSc/1/).

Comment: I don't really know how to reply on here yet, but that didn't seem to work. I changed my code a little bit too also.

Comment: @user2395454 Did you remove `style=\"display:inline; float:left; \"` ? (assuming you wan't it to look like the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/pLXSc/1/) I made).

Comment: I just edited my question with the new code, and now the images are right underneath one another.

Comment: @jadeallencook can you post your output , whether it be in a [jsfiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) or a separate file.

Comment: @jadeallencook I'm no php expert, but i've updated the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/caVSZ/1/) to how it should be shown in html.